# How to traverse in the xml based on a value of a tag to a different node

Tags: xml, xslt

**Input XML**

```
<root>
  <data>
    <reportable>
      <row index="1">
        <tn>name1</tn>
      </row>
      <row index="2">
        <tn>name3</tn>
      </row>
      <row index="3">
        <tn>currency</tn>
        <value>$</value>
      </row>
      <row index="4">
        <tn>name2</tn>
      </row>
    </reportable>
    <name1 type="table" cols="2" row="1">
      <row index="1">
        <fname>AAK</fname>
        <lname>BB</lname>
      </row>
    </name1>
    <name2 type="table" cols="2" row="1">
      <row index="1">
        <fname>KA</fname>
        <lname>A</lname>
      </row>
    </name2>
    <name3 type="table" cols="2" row="1">
      <row index="1">
        <fname>Arun</fname>
        <lname>Kumar</lname>
      </row>
    </name3>
  </data>
</root>
```

**Sample XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-
        microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/root/data/reporttable">
    <xsl:for-each select="row" >
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(tn,'name')">
          <xsl:call-template name='temp2'>
            <xsl:with-param name='pathValue' select="concat('../',tn)"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="tn='currency'">
          <curr>
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
          </curr>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="temp2">
    <xsl:param name="pathValue"/>
    <valueofFname>
      <xsl:value-of select="$pathValue/row/fname"/>
    </valueofFname>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Expected Output XML**

```
<valueofFname>AAK</valueofFname>
<valueofFname>Arun</valueofFname>
<curr>$</curr>
<valueofFname>KA</valueofFname>
```

> Here I have reached the tn, once I found the value of tn is "name1", 
>       then I would like to go to the table name1 by concating the node path 
>       and have to pass this has a parameter by calling another template(temp2). 
>       There i have to take the value from fname in the name1 table. i.e., let it 
>       be that i have passed the param name as "pathValue" with the value as 
>       "../name1". I want to fetch the value in the path by appending the 
>       /row/fname
>
> Then again when i see the value of tn as name3, then again i have to call
>       the same template with the parameter pathValue as"../name3" and like i 
>       mentioned above i have to fetch the value of fname in the name3 table
>
> Kindly help in traversing the name1, name2 and name3 nodes
>       based on the value of 'tn' in reporttable. 
>       Could someone help in how i can set a path that i would like to traverse.
>       Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output does not quite match your description. I am guessing you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-name" match="*" use="name()" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="data/reportable/row" >
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(tn, 'name')">
                <valueofFname>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('elem-by-name', tn)/row/fname"/>
                </valueofFname>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="tn='currency'">
                <curr>
                    <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                </curr>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the result is not a well-formed XML document (does not have a single root element).

Comment: Thanks Michael... Now I am able to traverse